# what's wrong with my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
ssh -f $user@$machine_name "cd $path; shard_path=`find . -name \"shard0\"`; cd $shard_path; mkdir temp"
```

The directory structure is $path/node0/shard0

In this script, the var `shard_path` is null, why? And the directory`temp` is constructed in the `~/` but not in the `shard0`.

Comment: off-the-topic, how about write a bash script on the remote machine, and ssh to execute that script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using double quotes around the command to send to the server, that is being expanded locally. It's trying to substitute `$path` and `$shard_path` based on their local values, and since `$shard_path` isn't defined locally, it expands to nothing.

You can avoid a lot of these quoting issues by using single quotes for the command to be executed on the server. The exact quoting that you need depends on exactly where these variables are defined. But from your comments, it sounds like this is the command that you need:

```
ssh -f $user@$machine_name "cd $path;"'shard_path=$(find . -name "shard0"); cd $shard_path; mkdir temp'
```

Comment: @SuperJin Help me out a bit here. What doesn't work? What are the results you expect, and what do you see? Is `$path` defined on the client or the server side? Can you  change the `cd` command to `echo`, in order to see what `$shard_path` is expanding to? Also, if you know that the directory structure is `$path/node0/shard0`, could you use that instead of `find`? For instance, `"cd $path/node0/shard0"`. Again, if something isn't working, replace it with `echo` to see what the variables are expanding to.

Comment: `$path` is defined on the client,so `echo $path` will be the directory path.but `$shard_path` is defined on the server, and `echo $shard_path` or `echo \$shard_path` doesn't work.I can't  use that instead of `find`, because I don't know the `node0` is what, maybe is `node1`,I just want to change in the right directory.

Comment: @SuperJin "doesn't work" doesn't tell me very much. What doesn't work? Does it print nothing? Print the wrong path? Can you post the exact command that you tried, and it's exact output, in your question?

Comment: `ssh -f xce@ns20.xce.n.xiaonei.com "echo $path; shard_path=`find . -name \"shard0\"`; echo \$shard_path"` ,the first `echo` prints the right path,but the second `echo` prints nothing

Comment: @SuperJin It's a lot easier if you paste this into the question, like I asked, instead of a comment. And include the exact output. One thing I notice: in your original command, you did `cd $path`, but since you changed it to an `echo`, you are now running the `find` command in your home directory, not in `$path`. If `$path` is outside of your home directory, the `find` command won't work. Remember to still do the `cd` if that's necessary for the later commands, or do `find $path` instead of `find .`

Comment: thank you for your answer, I do this `ssh -f xce@ns20.xce.n.xiaonei.com "cd $path; shard_path=find . -name \"shard0\"; echo \$shard_path"` , and the `echo \$shard_path` print noting

Comment: @SuperJin What happens if you log into the sever and run those commands manually? Also, are you including the backquotes in the `shard_path=find` command? I asked you to paste these commands into the question and not into a comment because the comments on StackOverflow are limited, and you can't put the exact command into the comments. Or you could use `$()` instead of backquotes, as those are generally preferred anyhow. `shard_path=$(find . -name \"shard0\")`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20606/discussion-between-brian-campbell-and-super-jin)

Answer (score 1):

From your discussion with Brian Campbell, I assume that the `$path` variable is on the local client and `$shard_path` is on the remote location.

Then try the following:

```
ssh -f xce@ns20.xce.n.xiaonei.com "echo $path; cd $path; shard_path=\$(find . -name \"shard0\"); echo \$shard_path;"
```

**Note:** If there is a possibility that there are multiple files called 'shard0', find will output many paths, so you might want to use
`shard_path_array=( \$(find . -name \"shard0\") );`
This puts find's output into an array, and you can then switch to one path using for example
`cd \${shard_path_array[0]}` (on the remote machine)

Comment: Glad I could help! Since it works, could you please accept the answer? cheerio

Answer (score 0):

$path is being expanded locally before the command is sent to the destination machine via ssh. Ditto $shard_path. If you want those values interpreted/expanded remotely, you need to escape the $, e.g. \$path.

[Here's a very thorough treatment on this subject](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4770/quoting-in-ssh-host-foo-and-ssh-host-sudo-su-user-c-foo-type-constructs).